# Does the weight of a mass effect the transfer function of a vertical mass-spring-damper system?

Tags: frequency

Usually in system dynamics, I dealt with horizontal mass spring dampers. Now in my advanced class I am dealing with vertical mass spring dampers. So a spring is hanging from the ceiling with a mass connected, and then the damped is under the mass. The damper is in some sort of oil and that is creating the "damping" effect.

In this problem, the spring is assumed to be negligible mass, but the damper has a mass, along with the weight that is acting as the mass.

I know that for a mass spring damper system (when its horizontal), the transfer function is
$$H(s)=\frac{\omega_{n}^{2}}{s^{2}+2\zeta\omega_{n}s+\omega_{n}^{2}}$$

But now the mass of the weight and damper are acting on this system. So does that affect the transfer function?

Comment: Where are the electronics in the question? I'll flag for migrating to physics.SE. (I also removed the `homework` tag, which is deprecated here.)

Comment: This seems to be a control system problem that could go on either site. As @greg is a pretty active user there and decided to come here to ask and that control theory is definitely something EEs often do in design I am leaving it here for now. Call it being greedy.

Comment: [Chat has a log of the rest of our discussion.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5974/discussion-between-kortuk-and-stevenvh)

Answer (score 2):

The mass of the weight and the damper were part of the horizontal system, too. Gravity simply introduces a bias force that adds to the force of the spring, shifting the rest position of the system. The dynamics are not affected.

Comment: So I am assuming that the transfer function does not change.. correct?

Comment: No, it does.  There's going to be an additional term in your conservation of force equations, F=ma, where a=g

Answer (score 2):

The electrical analogy of this is a series LCR circuit in which capacitance corresponds to mass and inductance corresponds to (1/spring rate). As Dave says, gravitational force introduces a bias which in the electical analogy is a dc current.

With 'ideal' components this bias will not affect the transfer function but to pursue the electrical analogy, a dc current could saturate a real inductor, causing it's inductance to fall. Similarly, excess force on a weak spring would cause it to over-extend causing it's spring rate to increase thus affecting the transfer function.